# MongoDB: Create an embedded document

Tags: python, mongodb, csv

I need to upload 2 CSV files as an embedded document to MongoDB.

So in the same database, I created 2 collections: `mainColv3` and `consoCol` for each CSV file and uploaded the CSV file as a document in each collection using python.

Now that I have these CSV files in the database, I need to copy all the documents inside of `consoCol` collection to `mainColv3` collection as an embedded document list. In some how The C1 is the master and consoCol the slave data and we have 1 to many relationship between mainColv3 - consoCol .

I tried the following code but I didn't get the right behavior:

```
db.mainColv3.update(
{_id:ObjectId("56cd9b802514971a205a9502")}, 
    {"$set":{"consomation":db.consoCol.find()}}
)
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

I Finally find out to how to do it:

db.mainColv3.update({_id:ObjectId("56cef0b92514971a205c30ac")}, {"$set":{"consomation":db.ConsoCol.find().toArray()}})